How to install npm package from private GitHub repo using yarn?
I have npm package in private GitHub repo. How could I install it using yarn v1 in Dockerfile?
Without Dockerfile on my machine I use
"package_name": "git+ssh://git@github.com/org_name/repo_name#branch"

and yarn install. There is no .npmrc.
In Dockerfile I tried to use my private key, but I got Permission denied (publickey).
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo "Host github.com \
    AddKeysToAgent yes \
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519" > ~/.ssh/config && \
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
COPY id_ed25519 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
COPY id_ed25519.pub ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
RUN yarn install


try to set 600 permission on the private key
